# Validating numericality with the attribute api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

The [numericality validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) does not seem to work with attributes declared with the [Attributes API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html)

```rb
  class Tester
    include ActiveModel::Model
    include ActiveModel::Attributes

    attribute :units, :integer

    validates :units, numericality: true
  end

  t = Tester.new(units: 'ABC')
  t.valid?                     # => true 
  t.errors.full_messages       # => []
```

I expected `t` to be invalid because `ABC` is not a number. This works if Tester is an ActiveRecord::Base. (Rails 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error because `ActiveModel::Attributes` casts the value to the defined type.

In your case `'ABC'` is cast to integer and `'ABC'.to_i #=> 0`. And `0` is obviously a number.

You can check that by checking the value of `t.units` after running your example code.

Comment: Any idea on how to get type coercion and validation to work together?